# How to test android app for Chromebook compatibility without having Chromebook hardware?

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-machine, google-chrome-os, chromebook

Google announced android apps support in Chrome OS on Chromebooks. Is it possible to test my android app on Chromebook without having Chromebook hardware? Any emulator or VirtualBox image, etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To run our app on a virtual Chrome OS device we have followed the following steps in Android Studio:

1. Install Chrome OS SDK add-ons for Android Studio

   - In Android Studio, select Tools open SDK Manager.
   - Click the SDK Update Sites tab. (3rd tab)
   - Click Add at the bottom of the window. The `+` icon
   - Enter the following name and URL, then click OK:

     Name: Chrome OS Repository
     URL:  **https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome_os_emulator/addon2-1.xml**
   - Click Add again.(+)
   - Enter the following name and URL, then click OK:

     Name: Chrome OS System Images
     URL: **https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome_os_emulator/sys-img2-1.xml**
   - Click Apply.
   - Click the SDK Tools tab and select the checkbox for Chrome OS device.
   - Click OK to install the Chrome OS device.
   - Click Apply.
2. Create an AVD using the AVD Manager

   From tablet category select Pixelbook (beta) hardware.
   The default RAM size for an AVD is 1536 MB. I recommend increasing the RAM for the AVD to 2048 MB.

Comment: It just terminates seconds after opening for me

Comment: If you tap on any of resources you will see this: <Error>
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist.</Message>
</Error>

Comment: I'm getting the same error as @TarasVovkovych

If you tap on any of resources you will see this: 
   <Error>
      <Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
      <Message>The specified bucket does not exist.</Message>
   </Error>


Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work now. “IO exception while downloading manifest”.

[Exclamation marks near to sites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze0uJ.png)

[Error message putting the cursor on the exclamation mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puLwa.png)

Comment: I'm getting the same issue... Any solution to this? @v_mil